# Existence of a solution to a boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations

Consider an ODE of the form
$$y''=f(x,y,y') $$
with $x \geq 0$, and initial conditions of the form 
$$y(0)=y_0>0, \\y'(0)=m_0. $$
I want to claim that under reasonable conditions (which I can't precisely formulate at the moment) on the function $f$, we have the following

> The solution $y$ with the initial conditions above will attain a negative value in its interval of existence, provided that $m_0$ is sufficiently large and negative.

I was wondering if such an existence result for boundary value problems is known. If so, I'd like to see a reference. Otherwise, I'd like help in formulating the statement properly.

Intuitively, the solution $y(x)$ behaves similarly to $y_0+m_0 x$ for $x$ near $0$, so taking $m_0$ large and negative should result in an intersection with the $x$-axis. However, I can't see why the interval of existence doesn't shrink in size as $m_0$ decreases, preventing such an intersection via a singularity.

Thanks in any case!